# PHP Check if 2 files exist at the same time

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if two files exist at the same time in the same sentences and not work.. when I separate the sentences in two conditionals it work but together nothing happen, no error, no warning NOTHING... 
Please any suggestion?

This is my simple code:

```
$folder_img_small = 'images/press/img_small/';
$folder_img_big   = 'images/press/img_big/';

$target = $folder_img_small;
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['img_small_1']['name']);

$target2 = $folder_img_big;
$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['img_big_1']['name']);

if ( (file_exists($target)) && (file_exists($target2)) ) {
    echo "One of the files already exists with the same name.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: use `||` (or) instead. Your code requires both exist at the same time. `or` allows you to test if "one OR the other" exists.

Comment: Thanks Bro it work! Was just a simple confusion with the concat symbol... God Bless you and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try using an `OR` for this

```
if ( (file_exists($target)) || (file_exists($target2)) ) {
    echo "One of the files already exists with the same name.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Try and see if it works. It simply compares if it exists either in 1st target or in the 2nd. Once in exists in any then....

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you understood my little explanation about the comparism so you can deal with such scenarios without assistance next time :) Happy coding!

Comment: @abelvf Can you accept my answer as the solution to your question to help others having same issues look at it to resolve theirs as well.